# "toggleClass" in my accordion

Tags: jquery

I have written a jquery script [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5VGXq/) 
But there is problem in the `$(this).toggleClass("active").next();` section. With this all the header tags will be in "active" class. How can I assign "active" class only for clicked tag?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove it from the previously clicked headers by calling [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) on the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), like this:

```
$(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bmJfj/1/).